# Issue with nnstart in matlab tool

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I'm doing a character recognition project using feature extraction and nueral network. I use matlab. I created a feature vector with 30 features.I have labeled the numbers as well using another variable. Using nntool I get the correct result. But when I use nnstart to generate the code I don't get a drop down list to select for the target. Input is ok. The input is with 48 columns with 30 rows each. ( 30 are the features and I have 48 samples) The target is 48 columns with 1 row( There I labeled the numbers) Can someone help me with this issue. 
Thanks in advance.[The scree shot is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dGHG.png)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem with the nnstart UI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use command line codes instead of GUI. Here, code is given. you can manually assign inputs and outputs.

```
% cancerInputs - input data.`
% cancerTargets - target data.
inputs =cancerInputs;
targets = cancerTargets;
% Create a Pattern Recognition Network
hiddenLayerSize = 30;
net = patternnet(hiddenLayerSize);
% Set up Division of Da
net.divideParam.trainRatio = 70/100;
net.divideParam.valRatio = 15/100;
net.divideParam.testRatio = 15/100;
% Train the Network
[net,tr] = train(net,inputs,targets);
% Test the Network
outputs = net(inputs);
```